# C# How to display vertical Histogram?

Tags: c#, input, histogram

I am very new to C# and I am trying to create a console application to create a vertical and horizontal histogram, made of stars. So I am asking the user for 8 numbers between 1-10 and printing their results onto the screen as a histogram. 
I need help with displaying the histogram vertically, I've done the horizontal one and can't figure out how to make it vertical. Here's what I've got so far: 
Would appreciate any help greatly. Thank you in advance.
I'd like it to look something like this:

```
*
*  *
*  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *(Height of row depends on numbers user enters.)
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise_3A
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            clsMainMenu MainMenu = new clsMainMenu();
            ConsoleKeyInfo ConsoleKeyPressed;

            do
            {
                MainMenu.DisplayMenu();
                ConsoleKeyPressed = Console.ReadKey(false);
                Console.WriteLine();
                switch (ConsoleKeyPressed.KeyChar.ToString())
                {
                    case "1":
                        clsHistogram Histogram = new clsHistogram();
                        Histogram.CreateHorizontalHistogram();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        clsHistogram HistogramV = new clsHistogram();
                        HistogramV.CreateVerticalHistogram();
                        break;
                }
            } while (ConsoleKeyPressed.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise_3A
{
    class clsMainMenu
    {
        public void DisplayMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. Create a Horizontal Histogram.");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Create a Vertical Histogram.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Esc to exit the Program.");
            Console.WriteLine("..................................");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise_3A
{
    class clsHistogram
    {
        string strNumberChosen = "";

        public void CreateHorizontalHistogram()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 10:");

            int[] intHistogramArray = new int[8];

            for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 8; intCounter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + (intCounter + 1) + " :");
                strNumberChosen = Console.ReadLine(); // Need Data Validation Here.             
            } // Populating Array.

            Console.WriteLine("Your Histogram looks like this: ");
            for (int intcounter = 0; intcounter < 8; intcounter++)
            {
                int intStarPlot = intHistogramArray[intcounter];
                while (intStarPlot > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(" *");
                    intStarPlot -= 1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            } // Display a Horizontal Array.
        }


        public void CreateVerticalHistogram()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 10:");

            int[] intHistogramArray = new int[8];

            for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 8; intCounter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter number " + (intCounter + 1) + " :");
                strNumberChosen = Console.ReadLine(); // Need Data Validation Here.
            } // Populating Array.

            Console.WriteLine("Your Histogram looks like this: ");
            for (int intcounter = 0; intcounter < 8; intcounter++)
            {
                int intStarPlot = intHistogramArray[intcounter];
                while (intStarPlot > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write(" * \n");
                    intStarPlot -= 1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            } // Display a Vertical Array.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way: Iterate over the values from the maximum down to 0 { iterate over the columns { if the column value is >= the value then print an asterisk }}. Another way: draw into an array, then print out the array the other way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little test program that might get you started on creating the Vertical Histogram. Notice I combined the last solution I provided for the Horizontal Histogram and made the code more universally applicable:

```
private static readonly char star = '*';
private static readonly uint minValue = 1;
private static readonly int maxValue = 10;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var list = GetHistorgramData();
     CreateHorizontalHistogram(list);
     CreateVerticalHistogram(list);
}

private static void CreateHorizontalHistogram(List<int> list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your Horizontal Histogram looks like this: ");
    //foreach(var value in list)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.PadRight(value, star));
    //}

    //Console.WriteLine("Or like this with LINQ");
    list.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(string.Empty.PadRight(n, star)));
}



private static void CreateVerticalHistogram(List<int> list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your Vertical Histogram looks like this: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < maxValue + 1; i++)
    {
        var displayLine = string.Empty;
        foreach(int x in list)
        {
            displayLine += ((x + i) - maxValue) > 0 ? star.ToString() : " ";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(displayLine);
    }
}



private static List<int> GetHistorgramData()
{
    var limits = "a number between " + minValue + " and " + maxValue + ": ";
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter " + limits);

    var list = new List<int>();

    do
    {
        var message = string.Empty;
        bool isNumber = false;
        bool isRightSize = false;
        int output;

        do
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();      
            isNumber = int.TryParse(input, out output);
            if(isNumber)
            {
                isRightSize = minValue <= output && output <= maxValue;
                message = isRightSize ? "That will do: " : "Try again - value is not " + limits + output;
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Try again - " + input + " is not a Number";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }while(!isNumber || !isRightSize);

        list.Add(output);
        Console.WriteLine("Entered number at position" + list.Count + " : " + output);
    }while(list.Count < 8);

    return list;
}
```

Vertical Results:

```
    *    
   **    
   **    
  ****   
  ****   
 ******  
 ******* 
********
********
```

for input:

```
Please enter a number between 1 and 10: 
2
Entered number at position1 : 2
4
Entered number at position2 : 4
6
Entered number at position3 : 6
8
Entered number at position4 : 8
9
Entered number at position5 : 9
6
Entered number at position6 : 6
4
Entered number at position7 : 4
3
Entered number at position8 : 3
```

---

**NOTE**:
I suggest you use the method `GetHistorgramData()` for both Vertical and Horizontal. 
You can decide whether you wish to use `LINQ` for the Horizontal Histogram or the `foreach` loop version. 
I think I could have made `LINQ` version for the Vertical Histogram, but I felt that might look confusing. 
You might want to restyle the Histogram a bit, but keep in mind the width of a space " " is different than that of the star "*". 
Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you again barns, this fixed my problem! You're amazing at this, thank you so much for your help! I really appiriciate it. :)

Comment: @Super Glad it fit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
  int currentValue = 1;
            bool allDone = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Histogram looks like this: ");

            while (!(allDone))
            {
                int x = 0;
                for (int intcounter = 0; intcounter < 8; intcounter++)
                {
                    if (intHistogramArray[intcounter] >= currentValue)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" * ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("   ");
                        x = x + 1;
                    }
                }
                if (x>=8) { allDone = true; }
                currentValue = currentValue + 1;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

output:

```
Your Histogram looks like this:
 *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
    *  *  *  *  *  *  *
       *  *  *  *  *  *
          *  *  *  *  *
             *  *  *  *
                *  *  *
                   *  *
                      *
```

If you want to have them *bottom-aligned*, you have to make some slight modigfications, this is just to give you an idea on how to start.

Comment: Hi Luuk, thank you so much for your help! I have implemented this and it's not working for some reason. I'll show you what I've got so far. Everything seems fine but nothing displays when it says "Your histogram looks like this:". Also, I would like it to go from bottom to top but thank you for not giving me all the answers. ;)

Comment: It is not showing anything because there are no values in your array `intHistogramArray`. (The update is missing, in the piece of code you have twice in your program, where you do your input)

Comment: I think I know what you mean but it still isn't working. How do I send my code back to you as the comments are too small to fit my code into. Many thanks Luuk :)

Comment: Your input is done in this line `strNumberChosen = Console.ReadLine();`, but the string strNumberChosen is not put in the array which is used to build the Histogram

Comment: I added the strNumberChosen = Console.ReadLine(); inside the for loop but it still doesn't display the stars for some reason. Sorry if this is a pain. I'm very new to this stuff and I really appreciate the help you're giving me.

Comment: Time to take a couse in [debugging](https://michaelscodingspot.com/debugging-part1/) 